# Get the maximum logged in application users and when

Tags: mysql

I have tried googling and checking questions on this site, but I think the terms "users" and "logged in" is throwing the answers.

I have an application that uses a MySQL database where User details are stored on the Users table. The MySQL server version is: 5.7.42-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server - (GPL).

I am trying to find the maximum concurrent users the application ever had, and when that was. Note that by *users* I mean users of my application, not database users. As a bonus, knowing the actual usernames (not just the number of users) would be helpful as well.

The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
 `user_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
 `last_logout` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1813 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The query I have written based on help from this site is as follows:

```
SELECT user_ID, username, last_login, last_logout, last_logout - last_login AS seconds
FROM Users
WHERE last_login < last_logout
AND last_logout > last_login
ORDER BY last_login;
```

But that is not giving me the results I want. Note that the last_login and last_logout columns are stored as datetime.

I've also tried to use a JOIN similar to the below, but that's also not working:

```
SELECT user_ID, username, last_login, last_logout, last_logout -last_login AS seconds
FROM Users A
INNER JOIN Users B ON (B.last_login <= last_logout)
AND (B.last_logout >= A.last_login_datetime)
AND A.user_ID <> B.user_ID;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us some sample data and the table structure for `Users`. You can run `SHOW CREATE TABLE Users;` and paste the result into your question for the structure.

Comment: Please tell us your MySQL version too.

Comment: Would you say your data might look something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/n4L9qYZB

Comment: @FanoFN That's almost exactly what it looks like :) Note that session times don't tend to be very long - the average is 641 seconds.

Comment: You can edit the data in the fiddle accordingly and from there, can you show us what kind of output/result you expected?

Comment: @FanoFN OK I've made user 1 and 2's session times overlap. Since they were both logged in at overlapping times on that day, they are classified as concurrent users (users 3 and 4 were logged in on different days). So I would expect the maximum concurrent users to be 2, which happened on 2023-01-01 08:05:00 (although if it's complicated, the time is less important than the date). As I mentioned, it would be a bonus if I knew it was Users 1 and 2 in the result, but that's not as important since if I know the date and/or time, I can just query logged in users at that date/time and get usernames.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `last_login` and `last_logout` strictly applies to the latest login session of a user. But if we are trying to find the maximum concurrent users the application ever had, wouldn't it be more appropriate to include all login history ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo That is an excellent point. In my application I only retain the session time of the last session, but I do retain all *login* events (as well as other events) in an Events table. I suppose if I also recorded all logout events in the Events table then you're right, I could apply similar logic to FanoFN's excellent answer to get the maximum concurrent users *ever*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT LoginDate,
       GROUP_CONCAT(username) AS 'Concurrent_users',
       COUNT(username) AS 'Total_users'
   FROM
(SELECT DATE(u1.last_login) AS LoginDate,
       u1.username,
       u1.last_login,
       u1.last_logout
FROM Users u1
JOIN Users u2
 ON u1.user_ID <> u2.user_ID
  AND u2.last_login BETWEEN u1.last_login AND u1.last_logout
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(u2.last_login) AS LoginDate,
       u2.username,
       u2.last_login,
       u2.last_logout
FROM Users u1
JOIN Users u2
 ON u1.user_ID <> u2.user_ID
  AND u2.last_login BETWEEN u1.last_login AND u1.last_logout) a
GROUP BY LoginDate;
```

It's a `UNION ALL` query build from

```
SELECT DATE(u1.last_login) AS LoginDate,
       u1.username,
       u1.last_login,
       u1.last_logout
FROM Users u1
JOIN Users u2
 ON u1.user_ID <> u2.user_ID
  AND u2.last_login BETWEEN u1.last_login AND u1.last_logout
```

The only difference is the switch between `u1` and `u2`. In the outer query, we group by login date, `group_concat` the username and count how many there is.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/Nl4Qp5OX

Comment: Yep, I think that's it :) Thank you! I'm surprised it's such a complex query and I couldn't find more examples here or on the web. How do other apps measure concurrent users? Doesn't everyone store login times on their databases, and at least have some way of storing a user's last session time?

Comment: Some might store each timestamp by row with an additional column to define the login/logout status. Also, using newer version of MySQL (version 8 and above) might have easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

tried this one

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS concurrent_users, GROUP_CONCAT(username) AS usernames, MAX(last_login) AS peak_time
FROM Users
WHERE last_logout IS NULL OR (last_login >= last_logout)
```

Comment: Thanks very much but that result doesn't seem correct. I'm getting 787 concurrent users, but I only have 1672 users total, and a lot of them are test accounts. I honestly don't think my app would have had more than maybe 20 concurrent users...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).